# Calling multiple functions to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I want to explain what I want to do and after where my problem is.

Initially I do a fetch request to load some data, since here is working okey.
After with one value of this data I want to do another fetch. For that I call another function *renderImage()*, where I do the fetch and I render the code that I want.

My problem is that is not rendering nothing, because is not changing the status into loaded. And of course fetch is asynchronous and needs more time.
And I don't know how do it that it works and more simple because I thinks that I doing it a little bit complicated.

This is my code:

```
class Dashboard extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
      }),
      loaded: false,
       datos: '',
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
}

    fetchData(){
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then ((responseData) =>{
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
            })      
        })
    }

    renderLoadingView(){
        return(
            <View>
            <Text>Cargando...</Text>
            </View>
            )
    }

    async renderImage(receta){
            const REQUEST_URL = "yyyyyyyy" + receta.user_id;
            const response = await fetch(REQUEST_URL);
            const json = await response.json();
            this.setState({ loaded : true});    
            return(       
                    <Card >
                        <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                            <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Thumbnail style={{width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25}} source={{uri: json.imageUrl}} />     
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                <Body>
                                    <Text>{receta.Titulo}</Text>
                                    <Text>{receta.Username}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </Left>
                        </CardItem>
                   </Card>             
            )           
    }


    renderReceta(receta){
            return this.renderImage(receta);                
    }

    render(){       
        if(!this.state.loaded){
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }
        else{
            return(
            <Container>
                <ListView 
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderReceta.bind(this)}
                />
                </Container>
                )
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to return in your `renderReceta` and `renderImage` and other functions that you run

Comment: @bennygenel thanks! i changed that but still not working. Now is entering in a loop and returning nothing

Comment: You are setting state while rendering your list items and this triggers re-render and that trigger another state setting and that triggers re-render so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not an "answer" but the question is a bit vague. This can be solved in many ways.

Option one: 
Load the array first, then show the list, and async "sideload" each row's images. 
Can be bad if you have a lot of images so watch out for that. Also you might load images here that you might never render (they are out of view, e.g. the user never scrolls to them), but you also wont load them twice to... pros and cons.

```
class Dashboard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
            }),
            loaded: false,
            datos: '',
            images: {

            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData(){
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then ((responseData) =>{
                this.setState({
                    loaded: true,
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
                });
                this.fetchImageUrls(responseData);
            });
    }

    fetchImageUrls(responseData){ //assuming respons data is an array of receta objects
        responseData.forEach(({user_id})=>{
            fetch("wwwsomewhere").then(r => r.json()).then(({imageUrl})=>{
                this.setState({
                    images: Object.assign(this.state.images, {
                        [user_id]: imageUrl
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    }

    renderLoadingView(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Cargando...</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    renderImage(receta){
        const {Titulo, Username, user_id} = receta;
        return(
            <Card >
                <CardItem>
                    <Left>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            {this.state.images[user_id] ?
                                <Thumbnail style={{width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25}} source={{uri: this.state.images[user_id]}} />
                                : "Loading (load thumb here?)"
                            }
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Body>
                        <Text>{receta.Titulo}</Text>
                        <Text>{receta.Username}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        )
    }


    renderReceta(receta){
        return this.renderImage(receta);
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.state.loaded){
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }
        else{
            return(
                <Container>
                    <ListView
                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow={this.renderReceta.bind(this)}
                    />
                </Container>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Options 2: 
Bundle upp all your loading into one and after resolve rerender.

```
class Dashboard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
            }),
            loaded: false,
            datos: '',
            recetas: {

            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData(){
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then ((responseData) =>{
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
                });
                this.fetchImageUrls(responseData);
            });
    }

    fetchImageUrls(responseData){ //assuming respons data is an array of receta objects
        //Load all images
        Promise.all(responseData.map(({user_id})=>{
            return fetch("wwwsomewhere").then(r => r.json());
        })).then((recetasArray)=>{
            //When all thumb objects (Recetas) have been resolved
            //map over the receta object array and create a hash (so you can access them by id later)
            this.setState({
                loaded: true,
                recetas: recetasArray.reduce((acc, receta)=>{
                    acc[recept.user_id] = receta;
                    return acc;
                },{})
            });
        });
    }

    renderLoadingView(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Cargando...</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    renderImage(receta){
        const {Titulo, Username, user_id} = receta;
        return(
            <Card >
                <CardItem>
                    <Left>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Thumbnail style={{width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25}} source={{uri: this.state.recetas[user_id]}} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Body>
                        <Text>{receta.Titulo}</Text>
                        <Text>{receta.Username}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        )
    }


    renderReceta(receta){
        return this.renderImage(receta);
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.state.loaded){
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }
        else{
            return(
                <Container>
                    <ListView
                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow={this.renderReceta.bind(this)}
                    />
                </Container>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Untested code but just wanted to share my ideas.

Comment: Thanks!! I changed some things but now is working. Thanks again!